# Trying to define a template function that takes a template argument

Tags: c++, templates, syntax

I'm trying to define a template function that takes a container, which is also a template type. I need to know what the template type of the container is (`E`) (so I can refer to it in the code, e.g. `E element = *iterator;`). Here's my attempt:

```
template <template <typename E> T>
void sort(T& container){ ... }
```

I think this means "`sort` is a template function that takes a template argument `T`. `T` is a template type that takes a template argument `E`".

However I get the error:

```
expected 'class' before T.
```

When I put 'class' there, it says:

```
variable or field 'sort' declared void
```

What am I doing wrong with the syntax?

Comment: Just take a plain type parameter `T` and then use `typename T::value_type`. What you are doing won't work with standard containers - they have more than one template parameter.

Comment: `T` isn't a type. You can't have a reference to something that isn't a type. By the way, Clang [handles both errors very well](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8dfca2ea54604829).

Comment: As chris alludes to, you really also have to give the template `T` the proper arguments. Actually, you are not interested in a template, but a specific template-instantiation (a class).

Comment: Gotta ask why not do this with iterators in the first place. If you really want a container version, write a forwarder template (and I'll warn you ahead of time, the standard containers have more parameters than you may first think).

Answer (score 1):

There are other ways to achieve the same function. What you need is a `template template` parameter. A working example is:

```
template <typename E, template <typename> class T>
void sort(T<E>& container){}
main(){}
```

In the template signature, `T` is declared to be a (dependent) type that takes another type parameter. That parameter itself (`E`) needs to be declared and supplied to `T`, just as you would use in `vector<int>`.

You could also use:

```
    template <typename E, template <typename, typename...> class T>
```

if your container type expects optional parameters such as traits.